# Update SQL from PHP with textbox and button

Tags: php, html

I am simply trying to create a home webpage to where we can enter the mileage hit update which grabs the vehicle, and current date then pushes it to the DB.

The code I have below displays correctly other than maybe formatting the number to have a `,` but that wouldn't be a necessity.

When I hit update I get `Notice: Undefined variable: mileage in /var/www/html/Oil/cars.php on line 60`

```
<link href="status.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body bgcolor = #000000>
<font color = "white">

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="86400"><style>
        body { 
            animation: fadeInAnimation ease 3s; 
            animation-iteration-count: 1; 
            animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
        } 
        @keyframes fadeInAnimation { 
            0% { 
                opacity: 0; 
            } 
            100% { 
                opacity: 1; 
            } 
        } 
    </style>
</head>

<center>
<font color = "red">




<?php
try {

    $db = new PDO("sqlite:/var/www/html/Oil/Vehicles.db");
    print "<center><table border=10 bordercolorlight=#383838 bordercolordark=Gray>";
    print "<tr><td class='toprow'><u>Vehicle</u></td><td class='toprow'><u>Mileage</u></td><td class='toprow'><u>Filter Size</u></td><td class='toprow'><u>Oil Capacity</u></td><td class='toprow'><u>Oil Type</u></td><td class='toprow'><u>Change Date</u></td><td class='toprow'><u>New Miles</u></td><td class='toprow'><u>Update</u></td></tr>";
    $result2 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM Cars');

    foreach ($result2 as $row) {

        print '<tr><td>' . $row['vehicle'] .'</td>';
        print "<td>" . $row['mileage'] . "</td>";
        print '<td>' . $row['filter'] .'</td>';
        print '<td>' . $row['oilCap'] .'</td>';
        print '<td>' . $row['oilType'] .'</td>';
        print '<td>' . $row['changeDate'] .'</td>';
    print '<td><form action="" method="POST"><input type="Text" name= "mileage"/><input type="hidden" name="vehicle" value="' .$row['vehicle']. '"/></td>';
    print '<td><button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="update">Update</button></form></td></tr>';
    }
    print "</table></center>";

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $mileage = $_POST['mileage'];
    print $mileage;
    $vehicle = $_POST['vehicle'];
    print $vehicle;
    $change = date("m/d/Y");
    print $change;

    $sql = "UPDATE cars SET mileage = :mileage, chageDate = :change WHERE vehicle = :vehicle";

    try{
            $db2 = new PDO("sqlite:/var/www/html/Oil/Vehicles.db");
        if (!($results = $db2->prepare($sql))){
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $db->errorInfo() . ") " . $db->errorCode();
        }elseif (!$results->bindValue(':mileage', $mileage)){
            echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $results->errorInfo() . ") " . $results->errorCode();
        }elseif (!$results->bindValue(':change', $change)){
            echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $results->errorInfo() . ") " . $results->errorCode();
        }elseif (!$results->bindValue(':vehicle', $vehicle)){
            echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $results->errorInfo() . ") " . $results->errorCode();
        }elseif (!$results->execute()) {
            echo "Execute failed:\n";
            print_r($results->errorInfo());
        }else{
            $count = $results ->rowCount();
            if($results ->rowCount() == 0)
                echo 'Error';
            else
                echo 'Changed!';
        }

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

}

?>
```

Maybe I'm not passing mileage correctly?

Comment: Where is your Line 60?

Comment: Is the notice typed or copy and pasted? Maybe `$row['milage']` is the line and it should be `mileage`? Please clarify question. Also HTML here looks verrry old.

Comment: @HarishST lines 59 and 60 would be ```$milage = $_POST['mileage']; print $mileage;``` @user3783243 I did have that messed up yes fixed it same error as far as the html I'm not sure what needs to change as that's all I know of it

Comment: Is this solved? There are a few answers below.

Comment: @kelvin yes it is I am just not able to accept my own answer. Ended up being a few spelling mistakes and needing to assign ownership of the DB to Apache, well more specifically www-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code,

The line 59 and 60 as you said are:

```php
$milage = $_POST['mileage'];
print $mileage;
```

You are assigning the value from form field to `$milage`, but you are trying to print a variable named `$mileage`. Check the spelling. They are different. So the variable you are trying to print is obviously `undefined`.

Change the code to,

```php
$mileage= $_POST['mileage'];
print $mileage;
```

Eventhough, it's just a typo. It can cause lot of debug time. So, try to understand the error and the problem will be somewhere beside it or it will have some relation atleast.

Comment: That worked but now I get ```Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/Oil/cars.php on line 71
Prepare failed: (Array) 00000``` :/

Comment: Can you mention the Code in Line 71?

Comment: 70 and 71 ```if (!($results = $db2->prepare($sql))){
   echo "Prepare failed: (" . $db->errorInfo() . ") " . $db->errorCode();```

Comment: Try `echo "Prepare failed: ";
        print_r($db->errorInfo());
        print_r($db->errorCode());` instead of `echo "Prepare failed: (" . $db->errorInfo() . ") " . $db->errorCode();`

Comment: Basically, the Error occurs when you use `echo` to `print an array`. Use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to print arrays.

Comment: Got it. Now I just get ```Prepare failed: Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) 00000```

Comment: You should check the documentation.Check Example #1 in this link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: From the documentaion: `If the database server successfully prepares the statement, PDO::prepare() returns a PDOStatement object. If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() returns FALSE or emits PDOException (depending on error handling). `. https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Also not the issue. Again was my spelling chageDate should be changeDate

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing an actual `value=''` in `<input type="Text" name= "mileage"/>`, so when Submitting `$_POST['mileage'];` is empty, and you get the notice.

Comment: So would it look like: ```<input type="Text" name="mileage" value='Text'/>```?

Comment: yes, and then `$_POST['mileage']` will equal `'Text'`

Comment: Sadly that was not the problem. Slight spelling on my end

Comment: @Ron No. It will not cause the Notice Undefined index. It will print a string of length 0 ie, `''`.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being 2 spelling issues on my part and then ran into a permission error on the DB.
After fixing all it worked as intended